# id() python difference between the == and 'is'

Tags: python

```
>> a=1
>> id(a);id(1)
1844525312
1844525312
>> id(a)==id(1)
True
>> id(a) is id(1)
False
```

what is the difference between the `==` and `is`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the limit of Python's integer interning here. The CPython implementation keeps a pool of small `int` objects (-5 through 257) in memory and reuses them as much as possible. That is why `id(a)` and `id(1)` return the same value; both `a` and the literal `1` refer to the same object. That value, though, is a much larger integer (namely 1844525312). That means that Python is free to (and does) allocate separate `int` objects for the return value of `id(a)` and `id(1)`, leading to the result you see. `1844525312 == 1844525312` is true, but `id(a)` and `id(1)` each return separate *objects* that represent the same value, leading to `id(a) is id(1)` returning false.

Note that with `a = 1; id(a) == id(1)` is not guaranteed to be true by Python itself; it's an implementation detail of a particular Python interpreter. It's allowed for an implementation to *always* allocate a new object for each new use, and it is allowed for an implementation to *always* reuse an existing object where possible. The only time Python guarantees that `id(a) == id(b)` for separate names `a` and `b` is if one name is assigned directly to the other (`b = a` or `a = b`).

Comment: You should use "is" instead of id()==id() because the second example can cause TOCTOU race condition when your program uses multiple threads.

Comment: It's a toy example demonstrating how the REPL interacts with interning; it doesn't need to worry about race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

**The == operator compares by checking for equality:**

**The is operator, however, compares identities:**

```
>> id(a)==id(1)
```

Since a=1 the value is same.

But for

```
>> id(a) is id(1)
```

Since id(a) and id(1) points to different objects, it is false!
Hope it helped you.